# Error while connecting localhost using socket.io in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to implement socket programming in my app using socket.io framework.

Code :-

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost/80")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])

var socket: SocketIOClient!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    socket = manager.defaultSocket

    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
    }

    self.socket.on(clientEvent: .error) {data, ack in

        print("error")

    }

    self.socket?.on(clientEvent: .disconnect){data, ack in

        print("disconnect")

    }

    socket.connect()
}
```

I do implement simple code here. but, while running my app getting following error:-

> 2019-02-25 18:07:21.298612+0530 DemoSocket[12023:236782] LOG
>   SocketManager: Trying to reconnect
>
> 2019-02-25 18:07:21.298925+0530 DemoSocket[12023:236782] LOG
>   SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: reconnectAttempt with data: [-68]
>
> 2019-02-25 18:07:21.299212+0530 DemoSocket[12023:241117] LOG
>   SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://localhost/80
>
> 2019-02-25 18:07:21.299356+0530 DemoSocket[12023:241117] LOG
>   SocketEngine: Handshaking
>
> 2019-02-25 18:07:21.299694+0530 DemoSocket[12023:241117] LOG
>   SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET
>   http://localhost/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
>
> 2019-02-25 18:07:21.312385+0530 DemoSocket[12023:241183] ERROR
>   SocketEnginePolling: Error during long poll request
>
> 2019-02-25 18:07:21.312561+0530 DemoSocket[12023:241183] ERROR
>   SocketEngine: Error
>
> 2019-02-25 18:07:21.312842+0530 DemoSocket[12023:236782] ERROR
>   SocketManager: Error
>
> 2019-02-25 18:07:21.313011+0530 DemoSocket[12023:236782] LOG
>   SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["Error"]

If any one have any solution to my problem then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.